# Angularjs not recognizing {{}}

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working through an angular tutorial and I have this output on the actual page:
{{product.name}} ${{product.price}}

my html and js are below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="container" ng-controller="StoreController as store">
<div class="product row" ng-repeat='product in store.products'>
    <h3>
        {{product.name}}
        <em class="pull-right">${{product.price}}</em>
    </h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and next the js

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', ['bootstrap-tagsinput']);

  app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.products= gems;
  });

  var gems = [
    { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 },
    { name: 'Bloodstone', price: 5.95 },
    { name: 'Zircon', price: 3.95 },
  ];
})();
```

Any help on how to actually display the contents of product.name would be appreciated. Also why is the html not recognizing these braces {{}} and displaying java script for them?

Comment: those braces don't appear in your code anywhere?

Comment: `var app = angular.module('gemStore', ['bootstrap-tagsinput']);`

Comment: whenever angular is not parsing your markup and is outputting the raw expressions, it generally means that angular itself, your app, or one of your controllers failed to load correctly.  What errors do you have in the console logs?

Comment: also, you defined your controller `StoreController as store` but then are referencing a `product` which isn't your controller, nor is it a property on your `StoreController`, so it's not clear where that is supposed to come from?  I think you are missing an ng-repeat element here, something like `ng-repeat = "product in store.gems"`

Comment: Yeah I just fixed the part with the ng-repeat and products.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
var app = angular.module('bootstrap-tagsinput', 'gemStore', []);
```

You can only have one main module, and your main app is gemStore so it should be something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('gemStore', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app='gemStore'>
<div class="container" ng-controller="StoreController as store">
<div class="product row">
    <h3 ng-repeat="product in products">
        {{product.name}}
        <em class="pull-right">${{product.price}}</em>
    </h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

your angular controller file,

```
var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

  app.controller('StoreController', function($scope){

     // var gems = [
    $scope.products=[  
    { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 },
    { name: 'Bloodstone', price: 5.95 },
    { name: 'Zircon', price: 3.95 },
  ];

  });
```

Want to test this code?
please use this fiddle made for you, 
http://jsfiddle.net/xfeh06zg/

Comment: made few changes as required. if you any specification, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle link but I think it might be an issue with the link and script tags in head

Comment: Your code will not work as you have made several mistakes ! Thats why, rather than suggesting you anything, I have come up with fiddle link.

Comment: Even your edited code will not work as still I can see the errors !

Answer (score 0):

you have no scope called `product`.
you have to define product `scope` in your `controller`
see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/09k8f5s4/52/)

> View

```
<div ng-app="gemStore">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div class="product row" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
      <h3>
        {{product.name}}
        <em class="pull-right">${{product.price}}</em>
      </h3>
 </div>
```

> **controller**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

  app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.products = gems;
  });

  var gems = [
    { name: 'Azurite', price: 110.50 },
    { name: 'Bloodstone', price: 22.90 },
    { name: 'Zircon', price: 1100 },
  ];
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that I did not have the correct script src here is what the first link and script tags should have been:

```
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>`
```

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>`